# Using Add with ForSingletonOf in StructureMap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

If have two classes `Class1` and `Class2` both implementing an interface `IInterface`.

And now, if I need a singleton instance of each of these classes, would this be the right way to implement it?

```
c.ForSingletonOf<IInterface>().Use<Class1>().Named("Class1");
c.ForSingletonOf<IInterface>().Add<Class2>().Named("Class2");
```

And then getting the instances like this:

```
container.GetInstance<IInterface>("Class1");
container.GetInstance<IInterface>("Class2");
```

Is there anything wrong in this approach or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to a specific implementation of IInterface you will need access to the container in order to request the specific named instance.
Constructor injection will always provide you with Class1 as that is what you have told structuremap to use for IInterface. So this will probably lead you to pass the container around which is a very bad idea.

If the objects need to be created as singletons, I would suggest not injecting as IInterface but as Class1 and Class2. They are first class citizens in your application and qualify for direct access.

```
c.ForSingletonOf<Class1>().Use<Class1>();
c.ForSingletonOf<Class2>().Use<Class2>();
```

Depending on what blogs you read, you may want to specify the implementation of Class1 and Class2 as interfaces attributing to what purpose they provide. This way you future proof them if the backing singleton of IClass1 or IClass2 should change.

```
public interface IClass1 : IInterface { }
public interface IClass2 : IInterface { }

-----

c.ForSingletonOf<IClass1>().Use<Class1>();
c.ForSingletonOf<IClass2>().Use<Class2>();
```

That is how I would go about it. Named instances in the container I have found are only useful when configuring the container as I have access to it. When it comes to dependency injection they are not useful as the named instance you require is specified by the class/interface name. If you require more than one implementation of the same interface, they qualify for their own interface imo